# how to eliminate the last occurence of a character in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using XML and XSL for printing the page in ASP.NET..

I am generating XML from Stored Procedure..

In that, I have the 'list of docs' columns.. Like Document 1, Document 2, Document 3,

In that I want to remove the appending comma character ',' (Only the last occurence)

I'm using

```
<xsl:value-of select="//UploadedDocs/UploadedDocs" />
```

this xsl value only has to substring ed..

If the String is **Document 1, Document 2, Document 3,**

I want the Output as **Document 1, Document 2, Document 3**

What method should I use??

Comment: Uh, the `string-join()` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
substring($string, 1, string-length($string) - 1)
```

will remove the last character of $string - regardless of what that character is.

We are assuming here that the $string is something that appears in the original XML document, not created by your XSLT - this part of your question is not entirely clear.

Comment: Good STRING expression, +1, and <year number="2015" message="HappyNewYear"/>